# How to make border on section of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to make shadow on section of tableview in ios. I have tried to make this with this method of table cell but it's not working.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Section:%ld  row:%ld", indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)])
    {

        CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 0, 0);

        BOOL addLine = NO;

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)

        {
             CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, 0.0, 0.0);

        } else if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {

        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));

        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), 0.0);

        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), 0.0);

  CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        addLine = YES;

        } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)

        {

        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));

        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), 0.0);
        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), 0.0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        } else {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), bounds.origin.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));

            addLine = YES;
        }
        layer.path = pathRef;
        CFRelease(pathRef);
        //set the border color

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
        layer.shadowRadius = 2;
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        layer.lineWidth = 1;
        if (addLine == YES)
        {
        CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width, lineHeight);
        [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
        }


        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView = testView;

        testView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
        testView.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
        testView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
        testView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
}
        NSLog(@"END row:%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

And I have to give shadow like this image:

[image]

Comment: i have added this but this not works.. in my  above code when i implement this , on last cell of section coming black

Comment: on selection of table view or on selection of table cell ?

Comment: no not a selection of table cell ... i need like image given.. without selection of table cell

Comment: so , u need the border for the table cells ?

Comment: yes..not particular cell .. i have  so many sections in table .. i need shadow on section..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VccVW.png ..plz check this link,, i need liike this...only

Comment: there are many ways to do it, it depends on ur requirement!!! You can use normal rows/normal sections/ custom cell/custom cell using xib!!!!

Comment: let me try to do it and update the answer!!!

Comment: Thank you sir...plz help me to do that

Comment: updated the answer @Dhruv

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use a collection view and create a custom collection view cell (so you can add borders to each cell in XIB).
2. You can create a custom table view cell add borders in XIB and remove table view line breaks. But this will not give you the exactly same view as you have in the shown picture. Better to implement my 1st suggestion.

You said you wanna draw the borders on selection to cell, then you can add transparent color in XIB and color them out on click to cell by implementing `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: i have not use custom cell of table view in this.. i want to use by default cell only ..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to apply border to the table cell , you can use the table cell content view and apply border for it.

```
  cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

But from your image, I suggest you to have a custom image with the border, and use table sections ,so that you will have the required spacing between the sections, and you can use the `custom image` to set the `background image` for the table section.

One way to do it is to add a custom `UIView` to the table cell `contentView`, and customise the `drawRect` for the `UIView`:

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{
    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.967 green: 0.423 blue: 0.211 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.508 green: 0.508 blue: 0.508 alpha: 0.369];

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 8.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 12.5, 183, 131.5)];
    [shadowColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 2;
    [rectanglePath stroke];


    //// Rectangle 2 Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 12, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 15, 176, 40)];
    [color setFill];
    [rectangle2Path fill];

}
```

This will give the result:

[image]

Make sure you set the proper height to the table cell. Also make changes to the height in the drawRectCode to fit your need!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

   ```
    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:0.2f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
   ```

   you can change the values as you need, i tried it and it worked.
2. You can set the border as image. take the needed image, put it as background imageview for your cell.

Good luck :)